# BASH: Explain about kill command

Tags: bash, kill

I was looking for a solution about a silent kill command and I successfully found the solution here , in the forum , by the command:

```
kill -9 "process_name" &> /dev/null
```

but , my question is:

What does " &> /dev/null " mean?

Any tips and advice will be appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

`&>/dev/null` redirects all of the output from STDOUT *and* STDERR to the bitbucket /dev/null.  Any output can be redirected to /dev/null and it is silently discarded.

Comment: &>/dev/null doesn't redirect STDERR, only STDOUT.

Comment: @brimble2010 - I'd agree with you if you were correct http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirecting-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error