# How can I manage to make stderr messages NOT print in the console?

Tags: linux, shell, stderr

I am currently writing a script that must, among other things, kill some processes.

I used the kill method and it works perfectly, except that, when I launch my script, some unwanted messages are print in the console saying for each of the processes that they have been "terminated".

I don't know how to get rid of these messages, so I would be grateful to anyone who can help me.

I would like these messages not to print inside the console, for they can be misleading. If I understand it correctly, those are error messages printed in the stderr stream.

Is there a way I can prevent these logs to print in the console ?

I have found on this site three issues that seem identical to mine, and proposed three differents solutions:

- [BASH: Explain about kill command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148755/bash-explain-about-kill-command/16148794#1614879)

> ```
> kill -9 $pid &> /dev/null
> ```

- [How to suppress Terminated message after killing in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81520/how-to-suppress-terminated-message-after-killing-in-bash)

> ```
> exec 3>&2
> exec 2> /dev/null
> kill $pid &> /dev/null
> exec 2>&3
> exec 3>&-
> ```

- [bash: silently kill background function process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5719030/bash-silently-kill-background-function-process)

> kill $pid
>
> wait $pid 2>/dev/null

But sadly none of these solutions change the behavior on my script (I always have "Terminated" messages). Does anyone have any other ideas? I am relatively new to Linux and does not master the redirection of outputs yet, so maybe I am forgetting something really obvious?

A huge thanks to anybody who will try to help!

Comment: It's more about how  you started the jobs than how you're killing them.  Can you show us the start commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subshell to *start* the processes and divert the output of the subshell:

```
pid=$(sleep 10 >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!)
kill $pid
```

The problem is that the *starting* shell will monitor and notice the termination of its child and report on it.

You also can be more drastic and switch off job control (which in a script might be just what you want):

```
set +m
sleep 3 & pid=$!
kill $pid
```